# Change the keep-alive timeout to detect a broken TCP connection

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, udp

I have been using UDP for long. But now its turn for TCP to get used by me. I want to use TCP sockets in Java and C application for MAC, Linux and Windows 7 OSes.

While using UDP, to know broken connection, I was tracking simple last packet receive time. If suppose node A does not receive any UDP packet within 5 seconds from node B, I was considering the connection broken. When there is no data to send from A to B or from B to A, both A and B will send small keep-alive packet (without data) to each other every second. This prevents the connection from being considered broken when not sending any data.

So, I want to know how the detection of broken connection works in TCP. Basically I want to know if a connection is broken on reading or writing to socket, and that only within 5 second.

I know that reading / writing will throw IOException in Java or return -1/0 in C, but how much time does TCP take to consider a connection as broken in each platform. And how can I change this **connection expire timeout** value?

Comment: You don't have to wait for TCP to tell you the connection is broken.  Just read from the socket (with `select` and a 5-second timeout) and if you time out instead of receiving a packet, then close the socket.  You can (sometimes globally) change the TCP timeout, but in this case just let TCP be TCP and have your app manage its own heartbeat...

Comment: @indiv I want to keep connection alive even when I do not send/receive any data.

Comment: @indiv I want to know TCP connection is broken within 5 second, if TCP connection is broken indeed.

Comment: You cannot control your TCP connection.  The network stack controls the TCP connection and it's not going to give up on a connection after 5 seconds.  In my above comment I explained what you have to do if you want a 5-second heartbeat.  If that's not satisfactory, you can wait for someone else to answer... I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: @Huko TCP keep-alive is the responsibility of the OS. You can't influence this using Java. On Window for example you don't have working TCP keep-alive.

Comment: @Robert this is very sad :(. Basically I want to know whenever node or network goes down immediately, so NOC can take action. While I can use UDP, but firewalls prevent me from using that.

Comment: @Robert then how much time approximately TCP will take to expire when connection is broken, in each OS?

Comment: @indiv posted above two comments, thanks for your valuable comments. Can you please reply my last comment if you can please.

Comment: @Huko when TCP connection breaks then you will get an exception (in Java side), that's how you know the connection was broken and in the `catch` block you can attempt to reconnect. I think it would be similar for C only that you don't have exception management in C (AFAIK).